# Publish webservice with no explicit dll dependency in visual studio 2010 and tfs build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, publish

We have a web-service with different APIs. To be more modular we use AreaRegistration of MVC to make APIs optional. So, my main project don't have any dependencies on my API project.
My problem is that when i want to publish my web-servicenone of the dlls of my APIs are deployed in my bin directory, so the web-service is empty, and the same when i build on my TFS.

How can i specify that i would like to add APIs dlls ton the bin folder when i publish my service ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try including the dll's to your project and set the properties to "always copy".